# Fill data frame with result from function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe, rbind

I have the following code to fill a data frame with the result from a function row-wise. The result of the function inside the loop is random-based (part of a simulation):

```
input <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:20),4,5), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
output <- data.frame()

j = 1
for (rowname in rownames(input)) {
   output <- rbind(output,ifelse(runif(5)+2>=rep(1/input[j,1],5),round(rgamma(5,shape=0.8, rate=2),0),rep(0,5)))
   j = j+1
}
rownames(output) <- rownames(input)
```

I would like to avoid the for loop and I guess there should be a way to do this in less lines and in a more efficient way in R. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Ideally, I would like to pass all arguments already during the creation of the output data frame.

Comment: @akrun I think we are trying to loop as many times as the number of rows.

Comment: I know, I use it just for iterating through the data frame. I am sure, there is a better way to this (maybe "length"), my knowledge of R is just too limited. The core issue I want to avoid is the for loop.

Comment: Please clarify what is happening inside the loop.

Comment: @zx8754 I added a brief clarification of what is happening inside the loop. Yet, I suppose, the way to avoid the for loop in this case does not depend on the ifelse function. It could be any other function returning a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ifelse(
  matrix(runif(prod(dim(input)))+2,nrow=nrow(input)) >= 1/input,
  matrix(round(rgamma(prod(dim(input)),shape=0.8, rate=2),0),nrow=nrow(input)),
  0)
```